# How can I merge 2 object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

How can I merge 2 object in javascript? e.g. if objB.a2 not exist then `objB.a2 = objA.a2`

```
objA = {
  a1: 
  a2: 
  a3: 
}

objB = {
  a1:
  a3:
}
for (var k in objB) {
  if (typeof objB[k] === 'undefined') {
       // objB[k] = 
  }
}
```

Comment: First: You have created an incorrect Javascript Object. Second you could simply iterate like you already do. Check if the key `k` exists in A when it doesnt exist in objB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can just do this:

```
$.extend(objB, objA);
```

This will merge all the properties of `objA` into `objB`. To merge them into a whole new object do this:

```
var objC = {};
$.extend(objC, objA, objB);
```

Without jQuery you can do it like this (this will add `objA`'s properties to `objB`):

```
for (var attrname in objA) { objB[attrname] = objA[attrname]; }
```

For more details see: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function merge(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {}, prop;
    for (prop in obj1) {
        obj3[prop] = obj1[prop];
    }
    for (prop in obj2) {
       obj3[prop] = obj2[prop];
    }
    return obj3;
}
merge(obj1, obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.extend() method from Underscore.JS as well. See details in http://underscorejs.org/#extend

It is a tiny and powerful JavaScript library of helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive a NEW object with properties of both objA and objB i suppose you could use a function like:

```
objA = {
  a1: 1,
  a2: 2,
  a3: 3
}

objB = {
  a1: 4,
  a4: 5
}

function merge(objA, objB){
  var o = {};
  for (prop in objA) //copy objA props to new object
    o[prop] = objA[prop];

  for (prop in objB) { //copy objB props to new object
    if (o[prop] === undefined) //check if the property name is used already
      o[prop] = objB[prop]; // if the prop name is not used - assign it
}
  return o;
};

console.log(merge(objA, objB)); //check the result!
```